# Questions about TikZ and dot grids

Tags: tikz-pgf

I apologize if a) this question has already been answered, and b) this is the wrong place to post this question.

I'm very new to TeX, and I'm trying to make my own notebook paper, as I haven't been able to find a notebook I like.

The ideal setup is Cornell notes on one side, with a dot grid in the notes block. The opposite side would have a Rhodia-spaced dot grid on it.

I have the following MWE, built from snippets I've pulled online:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[letterpaper,hmargin={0mm,3mm},vmargin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz, ragged2e} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[step=.7cm,gray!20,very thin] (4.9,4.9) grid (20.5,25.8); %this is the notes box that I want a dot grid in
\draw [line width=1pt, black] (0,4.9) rectangle (20.5,0); %summary box
\draw [line width=1pt, black] (0,25.8) rectangle (20.5,0); %main box
\draw [line width=1pt, black] (4.9,4.9) rectangle (20.5,25.8); %Grid box
\node at (2,4.5){Summary:};   
\node at (4,26.6){\parbox[t][2cm][c]{4cm}{\raggedright Subject:\smallskip \\
Date:}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[ scale=.5]% copies Rhodia's dot spacing.
\foreach \x in {0,...,41} % Number of columns of dots
\foreach \y in {0,...,53} % Number of rows of dots. If you change the spacing or margins, you'll have to play with these x and y ranges to make sure you have the right amount for the page.
{
    \fill[blue!75] (\x,\y) circle (0.06cm); % this is the thickness of the dots, blue because I like blue.
}       
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`
```

I'm sure there's an easier/better way to do this, I just don't know what it is and my google-fu apparently isn't good enough.

My problem is in line 10, where I've got the grid generated. I'd like to have the same dot grid that starts on line 19 in that box. I can't figure out how to do it...

I appreciate any help that anyone's able to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like this

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[letterpaper,hmargin={0mm,3mm},vmargin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz, ragged2e} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (4.9,4.9) rectangle (20.5,25.8); %this is the notes box that I want a dot grid in
        \begin{scope}[scale=0.5]
            \foreach \x in {0,...,41} % Number of columns of dots
            \foreach \y in {0,...,53} % Number of rows of dots. If you change the spacing or margins, you'll have to play with these x and y ranges to make sure you have the right amount for the page.
            {
                \fill[blue!75] (\x,\y) circle (0.06cm); % this is the thickness of the dots, blue because I like blue.
            }
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
    \draw [line width=1pt, black] (0,4.9) rectangle (20.5,0); %summary box
    \draw [line width=1pt, black] (0,25.8) rectangle (20.5,0); %main box
    \draw [line width=1pt, black] (4.9,4.9) rectangle (20.5,25.8); %Grid box
    \node at (2,4.5){Summary:};   
    \node at (4,26.6){\parbox[t][2cm][c]{4cm}{\raggedright Subject:\smallskip \\ Date:}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[ scale=.5]% copies Rhodia's dot spacing.
    \foreach \x in {0,...,41} % Number of columns of dots
    \foreach \y in {0,...,53} % Number of rows of dots. If you change the spacing or margins, you'll have to play with these x and y ranges to make sure you have the right amount for the page.
    {
        \fill[blue!75] (\x,\y) circle (0.06cm); % this is the thickness of the dots, blue because I like blue.
    }       
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Probably there are more elegant solution, I just tried to reuse as much of your code as possible.